# How to deploy Integer value to spring boot application using helm3?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes-helm

We are using helm3 to deploy our spring boot application to k8s cluster.

we are passing environment variable using helm **values.yaml** file but i figure out that we can send **integer** value it should always be in **string** formate.

because of that **@Configuration** failed to map string value to integer i just want to know how i can do this in spring boot app.

I did something like below and it worked for me but i just want to know is it the right way of doing this?

```
 public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = Integer.valueOf(value);
 }
```

I want below code to work fine with helm deploy

```
@Configuration
@Getter //Another problem is i am not able to use the feature of lombok because of this
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties("initializer.service")
public class InitializerPropertyConfig {
    private Integer value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Helm charts, to set value to Int

```yaml
factor: {{ int .Values.server.nodeFactor}}
```

or

```yaml
port: !!int "80"
```